# String to const char * in c++ puts garbage at end

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have a struct that needs to store const char * for later. The string gets destroyed by then. The code that i have till now for the same is

```
    HttpRequest* send(string reply)
    {
            int len = strlen(reply.c_str());
            char *buffer = new char[len+1];
            strncpy(buffer, reply.c_str(), len);
            cout << "LEN:"<<reply.length()<<endl;
            cout << "OG:"<<reply<<endl<<"TC:"<<buffer<<endl<<"CS"<<reply.c_str()<<endl;
            this->res.response = "test";
            return this;
    };
```

`res.response` is the char * that i want to store the value in. The output from cout that i am getting is

```
LEN:5
OG:hello
TC:hello�������������������q{
CShello
```

This behavior is pretty strange to me. Can someone please explain what i am doing wrong. Also the above code shows me using `strlen` but i am getting the same result using `length()` in c++ also.

Also it is worth mentioning that this happens only the first time that i invoke this, after that it goes fine.

Comment: [FYI] `strlen(reply.c_str());` can be replaced with `reply.size()`

Comment: @NathanOliver i mentioned that also. I thought the cause of error was something that so i posted the last copy of code that i had which used strlen :)

Comment: Ah.  I was wondering why use used `length` later on in the code but you did not use it for the string size.  Also is there a reason you need to copy the string into a char array?  As is you have created a memory leak as you never deleted the buffer.

Comment: I am using a httpServer that takes in const char *. So this is just for that internal engine. It handles memory free internally :)

Comment: Does HttpRequest come from a third party library? Which one?

Comment: @n.m. that is my own struct. But just in case i am using libmicrohttpd by gnu

Comment: Consider using `std::string` throughout your own code. Use `char*` only to interface with code you cannot change.

Comment: @georoot If the function you are calling expects a `const char *` then you can still use a `std::string`.  You just need `call_function_that _takes_const_char*(string_variable.c_str());`.

Comment: @n.m. that is exactly the use of this function. It passes that into microhttpd internal engine and takes care of everything from there on

Comment: @NathanOliver string is defined in a hook that i am using and is destroyed by the time it reaches for polling which is how microhttpd works :)

Comment: I don't see where it passes something to some third-party function. As posted, the only `char*` you have here comes from your own struct.

Comment: @n.m. that char * is directly passed into reponse, I just made stuff easier and make a separate function out of it because the rest of code is too big and probably not a very good idea to post here. Overall the concept is that i have url and function pointer map. I call the function from microhttpd. It invokes send and stores `const char*` which later i refer in microhttpd response directly as `request->res.response`

Comment: "I just made stuff easier" No you didn't. "stores const char*" That's precisely the mistake. Don't store legacy C stuff. Store C++ objects. "which later i refer in microhttpd response directly as request->res.response". **Then** you convert the C++ string you store to a `char*`, like this: `some_microhttpd_function (..., ..., this->response.c_str(), ...);` See? No manual buffer allocation, *no manual buffer deallocation*, and no mucking around with poorly designed C APIs.

Comment: @n.m. Here is the flow . MHD provides one callback only. I have a map of string,function pointer. For the time being lets call the MHD callback as `mhd_clb`. inside `mhd_clb` i check the url. If there is a match, i call the function that is mapped to that url which returns a struct containing const char *. The string is not accessible in `mhd_clb`. And even if it was, MHD uses polling for handeling requests and destroys char* internally. If i used a string then the pointer to `const char*` would also be destroyed after the function ends, but MHD wants that after function.

Comment: No, the pointer to `const char*` that c_str returns doesn't get destroyed unless you modify or destroy the string itself. If it's OK to store `const char*` somewhere, it is also OK to store  an `std::string` and use its `c_str`.

Comment: Yeah but the string will be destroyed because of polling. That is internals after function call. I can't keep the string. Only need const char *. MHD runs as a daemon so a little complicated that way :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You never put the null terminator:

```
char *buffer = new char[len+1];
strncpy(buffer, reply.c_str(), len);
buffer[len] = 0; // <-- HERE
```

`strncpy` doesn't add it.

Comment: thanks a lot. it works. Can't accept answer now will have to wait to 12 mins :)

Comment: I wonder why people +1 misleading answer. `strncpy` does add it if there is room, so problem is not missing code shown but that buffer size needs to be passed to `strncpy`, not string length

Answer (score 3):

Your arguments to `strncpy()` make the function misunderstand that there is no space for terminating null-character, so it isn't written. Correct the argument like

```
strncpy(buffer, reply.c_str(), len+1);
```

In this code, it is guaranteed that the length of buffer is sufficient to store the string, so you can simply use `strcpy()` instead of the `strncpy()` like this:

```
strcpy(buffer, reply.c_str());
```

You can use [`strdup()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) function if your system supports it. Using it, the lines

```
int len = strlen(reply.c_str());
char *buffer = new char[len+1];
strncpy(buffer, reply.c_str(), len);
```

can be replaced with

```
char *buffer = strdup(reply.c_str());
```

Note that `strdup()` is a function from C and it uses `malloc()` internally, so you must use `free()`, not `delete[]`, to free the memory allocated via `strdup()`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `strncpy` until you've **read** and **understood** its documentation. And then don't use it. It's a very specialized function, and there's no need to deal with its quirks here. The code in the question allocates enough space for the result, so just use `strcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this statement

```
strncpy(buffer, reply.c_str(), len);
```

does not copy the terminating zero ( '\0' ) of the original string to `buffer`.

You should use the standard C function `strlen` with objects of type `std::string` only in case when the objects contain embedded zeroes. Otherwise use member functions of the class `std::string` `size` or `length`.

Instead of the standard C function `strncpy` you could use standard C function `strcpy` to copy the zero-terminated string in the buffer.

For example

```
    char *buffer = new char[len+1];
    strcpy( buffer, reply.c_str() );
```